# @media queries not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have tried everything I found, without result.

I made a very simple web page with media query. It works fine in desktop, but when I open it on any mobile, the media queries are not working.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no, minimun-scale=1.0, maximun-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scordatura</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Scordatura - Próximamente">
    <meta name="keyboards" content="scordatura, vigo, a coruña, galicia">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello,<br>my name is<br>Scordatura,<br>nice to meet<br>you.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
h1{
    font-size: 72px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
    h1{
        font-size: 64px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 350px){
    h1{
        font-size: 52px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px){
    h1{
        font-size: 38px;
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, the smallest mobile device is 320px wide, and that is `iPhone <= 5`, and `iPhone SE`, so your `max-width: 300px` rule will never run.

Answer (score 2):

Your media query does not match with respective breakpoint resolutions. Your breakpoints only works for Extra Small devices (like the old Nokia, Blackberry...)

Use the following breakpoints instead,

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...} 

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...} 

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. But what I do not understand is that the lines of text in the desktop version occupy up to 400px, and in mobile (which is supposed to have more width) the text lines exceed this size. I do not know if I explain myself.

Comment: I believe you are talking about Responsive layout. When you have more text you get a horizontal scroll and have to scroll horizontally to see more more text. What you actually want is to wrap the text down vertically. Am I right?

Can you post any screen shot?